# Java Build Path Error

Tags: android

How can I fix this error - 
Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/Android/Documents/eclpiseproject/codes/android/aproject/libs/._android-support-v4.jar' in project 'aproject' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP

Comment: just delete/remove.  is this path is correct ...ject/codes//android/a...?

Comment: sorry, can't understand your comment. what is that?

Comment: Right clicl your project goto BuildPath-->configureBuildpath... in that you can see library tag.

Answer (score 1):

I have just deleted android-support-v4.jar from the project and added it back using 'Android Tools -> Add Support Library' and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Developer Guide has a quite complete section on this topic. If you follow the steps you should be able to fix this problem.

-> http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the support library.

Right click the project in Eclipse > Android Tools > Add Support Library.

The support library is not packaged as part of the Android SDK but offers more components. It needs to be added though if you are using a component from it.

Wise to clean your project once added as well.

Comment: Already tried this one but its not working. still have the errors